# Blank page after chapter title when table is used

Tags: tables, blank-page

I am having a problem with a blank page appearing after the title page whenever only a table is in the chapter. So the chapter is 2 pages, the first is blank and the other is where the table is. Any suggestions?

```
\chapter*{List of A}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of A}

\begin{table*}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c}

    \textbf{XXX} &  XXX  \\
    \textbf{XXX} &  XXX \\

  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please complete your code in order to make it compilable for us. Why do you use `table*` with that asterisk? Do you need that `[H]` specifier? Always recommended to start without it. If you do not want the table to float somewhere, just put it in a `\begin{center}\end{center}` instead of the `table*`. You are having 4 columns but use just two.

Answer (score 2):

A `table*` double column float always goes to the *next* page.
If you want a one column appendix in an otherwise two column document use

```
\onecolumn
\chapter*{List of A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of A}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \textbf{XXX} &  XXX  \\
    \textbf{XXX} &  XXX \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Also: you can not have two-column floats (`table*`) with `H` or `h`